# Inserting pandas_market_calendars time value into pandas timestamp value

Tags: python, pandas

With the `start_of_day()` function below, I'm attempting to return timestamps of the NYSE market open date and time for the current week.  I am not using this in a pandas dataframe, I'm just using pandas time functions because they're some of the only functions that I've found that are specific to market dates and times that incorporate holidays.

In this particular case, I'm trying to return timestamps of:

```
2022-01-18 09:30:00
2022-01-19 09:30:00
2022-01-20 09:30:00
2022-01-21 09:30:00
```

(Above would not return `2022-01-17 09:30:00` because it was a holiday)

code:

```
# test.py

import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
import pandas
import time
now = pandas.Timestamp.now()

def start_of_week(multiplier, format='ms'):
    obj = now + pandas.tseries.offsets.Week(multiplier, weekday=0)
    obj = pandas.Timestamp(obj).floor(freq='D')
    if format == 'ms':
        obj = int(time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) * 1000)
    return(obj)
print(start_of_week(-4))

def start_of_day():
    nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
    print(f'type: {type(nyse.open_time)}')
    print(f'time: {nyse.open_time}')
    market_days = nyse.schedule(start_date=start_of_week(-1, None), end_date=now)
    for date in market_days.index.to_list():
        print(f'type: {type(date)}')
        print(f'date: {date}')
        print(f'time pieces: {nyse.open_time.hour} {nyse.open_time.minute} {nyse.open_time.second}')
        print(f'new timestamp: {pandas.Timestamp(date, hour=nyse.open_time.hour, minute=nyse.open_time.minute, second=nyse.open_time.second)}')
start_of_day()
```

```
# python3 test.py
1640581200000
type: <class 'datetime.time'>
time: 09:30:00
type: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
date: 2022-01-18 00:00:00
time pieces: 9 30 0
2022-01-18 00:00:00
type: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
date: 2022-01-19 00:00:00
time pieces: 9 30 0
2022-01-19 00:00:00
type: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
date: 2022-01-20 00:00:00
time pieces: 9 30 0
2022-01-20 00:00:00
type: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>
date: 2022-01-21 00:00:00
time pieces: 9 30 0
new timestamp: 2022-01-21 00:00:00
```

How can I make `new timestamp` incorporate the `datetime.time` objects so it will return the timestamps in the intended format?

Kind regards.

**Solution**
Use `pandas.DateOffset()` to offset hours, minutes and seconds instead of `pandas.Timestamp()`:

```
# test.py
import pandas_market_calendars as mcal
import pandas
import time
now = pandas.Timestamp.now()

def start_of_week(multiplier, format='ms'):
    obj = now + pandas.tseries.offsets.Week(multiplier, weekday=0)
    obj = pandas.Timestamp(obj).floor(freq='D')
    if format == 'ms':
        obj = int(time.mktime(obj.timetuple()) * 1000)
    return(obj)

def start_of_day():
    nyse = mcal.get_calendar('NYSE')
    market_days = nyse.schedule(start_date=start_of_week(-1, None), end_date=now)
    for date in market_days.index.to_list():
        print(date + pandas.DateOffset(hour=nyse.open_time.hour, minute=nyse.open_time.minute, second=nyse.open_time.second))
start_of_day()
```

```
# python3 test.py
2022-01-18 09:30:00
2022-01-19 09:30:00
2022-01-20 09:30:00
2022-01-21 09:30:00
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it addresses a single question.  As written, your question is too broad.

Comment: is that better?

Comment: What is the intended format?

Comment: `2022-01-18 09:30:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
pandas.DateOffset(hour=nyse.open_time.hour, minute=nyse.open_time.minute, second=nyse.open_time.second)
```

Original question updated.